# How to link depending on language Zend

Tags: zend-framework, multilingual

The application is in Zend Framework. It is multilingual and menu-buttons get translated in english or dutch using languagefiles. But how can I redirect using the menu buttons to other content using the same link?
For example en version links to ../Support and I want the nl version link to ../Help
The page in dutch wil have different content (text, images) so I will have a different index.phtml, indexnl.phtml.

I didnt find information on this site that actually explained this good for a non-zend-expert.
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this.

**Example 1**

Create separate routes that point to *separate* actions. So:

- `/Support` => `supportenAction()` which will by default render `supporten.phtml`
- `/Help`    => `supportnlAction()` which will by default render `supportnl.phtml`

**Example 2**

Create separate routes that point to *a single* action. So:

- `/Support` => `supportAction()`
- `/Help`    => `supportAction()`

Then in the action you render the correct view depending on the URL:

```
$this->render('index' . $language);
```

Depending on your controller code's structure you might prefer either of these examples.

Comment: I did see you're answer a while ago, only just figured out how to thank you for helping me out. You're suggestions are most useful.